# laravel 8 module form error The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, html, module, laravel-8

**i am confused with routes and how to specify the path . **
**web.php- this route is inside my module called events**

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    Route::prefix('event')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/create', 'EventController@index');
    });
    
    Route::post('/create', 'EventController@store');
```

**blade file-i have a form which calls create**

```
                      <form class="form-horizontal" action="../create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

**controller-here in store method i store the get thevalues fromthe user and storeitin the db **

```
function store(StoreCompanyRequest $req)
    {
        //
        $req->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'title'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required',
        'category'=>'required',
        'sdate'=>'required',
        'edate'=>'required',
        'address_address'=>'required',
        'address_latitude'=>'required',
        'address_longitude'=>'required',
      'images' => 'required',
      'images.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,csv,txt,pdf|max:2048'
    ]);

    abort_unless(\Gate::allows('company_create'), 403);

    if($req->hasfile('images')) {
        foreach($req->file('images') as $file)
        {
            $image_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $image_name);
            $imgData[] = $image_name;
        }
        $event = new Event;
        $event->name=$req->name;
        $event->save();
        return view('/home');
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask you to share example code using code blocks instead of images? The editor provides the code blocks functionality using standard markup. Sharing example code that way is generally more helpful because it allows the readers to copy and paste the code when trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i have added the code kindly check - @AttilaVečerek

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `action="/create"` in your form like so:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

I don't work with PHP and have no prior experience with Laravel but I can see that you are creating a route for the `POST /create` endpoint. With your current form object you reference the route action with a relative URL. So, if the form is on a page under the `/path/to/form` route, then the form submission results in a call to the `POST /path/to/create` route instead of the (maybe) intended `POST /create` route.

Comment: Thanks for answering now the error is gone but the values are not updating in database.

Comment: I’m glad it worked. I would consider this question answered then. You may ask about your database issue in a separate question 